# What does this shell-script line ( IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "$passPercent" )within brackets do

Tags: bash, shell

What does this shell-script line `( IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "$passPercent" )` within parenthesis is doing. 
Please also explain what each parameter is used for in this line .

$passpercent is actually a variable which is storing some curl data in it.

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=IFS%3D%27%3A%27+read+-r+-a+array+%3C%3C%3C+%22%24passPercent%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read -a array` reads and splits the text from standard input into the variable `array`. The splitting happens on the value of `IFS` which is set to colon for the duration of this operation.

The `-r` option to `read` disables some legacy behavior with backslashes, and should basically always be used unless you are trying to emulate how the shell itself handles backslashes.

The "here string" `<<<value` passes `value` as standard input to the process.

Parentheses cause the command to be run in a subshell. It doesn't particularly make sense here; often, we use a subshell to limit the scope of a variable assignment (overriding `IFS` locally perhaps; but here, `IFS` is only assigned for the duration of `read` anyway) or change of working directory.

Perhaps I should specifically point out that

```
variable=value command
```

sets the value of `variable` just for the duration of the execution of `command`, which is quite different from

```
variable=value; command
```

which sets the value of `variable` from here on, and then executes `command` and any subsequent code with the variable set to this value until it gets reassigned again, or this shell instance terminates.

So, in essence, you are creating a new shell instance, setting an array variable by splitting the input variable on colons, and then immediately losing that value when this subshell exits. If you just wanted nothing to happen, `:` would be briefer, `sleep` would take more time and waste less CPU, and performing some arithmetic in a tight loop would consume more CPU. And if you wanted the result of the assignment to be useful, don't perform it in a subshell (i.e. take out the parentheses).

For what it's worth, the "here string" redirection is a Bash feature (though it is slated to be included in a future version of POSIX `sh`) and, of course, so are arrays.